# Joined: 10/13/2008 Posts: 89 error on Arabic language setting with DNN 7

Tags: dotnetnuke

i have a site with 2 language

English (default) & i add the new language Arabic(ar-SA) in ddn 7

the issue that i cant access any setting for module  or site setting or edituser for example
its give me an error

A critical error has occurred. Valid values are between 1318 and 1450, inclusive. Parameter name: year

Answer (score 0):

Saudi Arabia uses the [Islamic calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar).

Currently, it's the year 1434, hence why you see the error.

Comment: error is Valid values are between 1318 and 1500.this error is come due to en-us calendar.some language issue.first this error comes in module setting than solve by this code
  datepickerStartDate.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            datepickerEndDate.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: In the Islamic calendar, the year is currently 1434 (not 2013).